# accessing model that belongs_to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a model 'Galleries', which has the 'has_many' relationship with 'Exhbition Images' (and  opposingly the belongs_to).

I want to display the images associated with each gallery via the Gallery model. However I am encountering the error

```
undefined method `exhibition_images' for #<Gallery::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000108159dd0>
```

when i try to implement this line of code

```
gallery index:

<%= @gallery.exhibition_images.each do |exhibition_image| %>
  <%= exhibition_image.title %>
<% end %>
```

I am sure this is very simple and I am missing something obvious.

Galleries controller

```
def index
  @gallery = Gallery.all
end
```

Gallery model

```
    class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
belongs_to :guide
has_many :exhibition_images
accepts_nested_attributes_for :exhibition_images
    end
```

Exhibition Images

```
class ExhibitionImage < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :gallery

has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "100x100", guide: "500x500" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

end
```

SCHEMA

```
create_table "exhibition_images", force: true do |t|
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
t.integer  "gallery_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

end

```
create_table "galleries", force: true do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.string   "slug"
t.integer  "guide_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
undefined method `exhibition_images' for #<Gallery::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000108159dd0>
```

You are trying to access `exhibition_images` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.  You have a relation object because you're calling:

```
@gallery = Gallery.all
```

That gives you a scope that you can use to chain together more query conditions.  You need to get an individual gallery object to be able to call `exhibition_images`.  You can do this by calling `first` on `@gallery`, or you need to execute the query and iterate through the results:

```
<%= @gallery.each do |gallery| %>
  gallery.exhibition_images.each do |exhibition_image| %>
    <%= exhibition_image.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you do that, however, I'd be sure to eager load the `exhibition_images`:

```
@gallery = Gallery.includes(:exhibition_images).all
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `@gallery` contains an array of Gallery objects.

In your controller you should have:

```
@galleries = Gallery.all
```

And then iterate over the `@galleries` array

```
<% for gallery in @galleries %>
  <%= gallery.exhibition_images.each do |exhibition_image| %>
    <%= exhibition_image.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```